# Tool for creating pie charts

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, diagram

I need a tool for creating high quality customizable pie charts, then export them to some graphic format (e.g. png).

I need something which allows me to put in some data and which is more customizable than OpenOffice.org.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_wizard.html)?

Not exactly what you asked for, but this may work anyways. Link is to a pie chart wizard.

Comment: Yes, this is quite good solution. I've found that many web apps offer automatic creation of high quality charts - better that eg. open office.

Answer (score 1):

`graphviz`, optionally with one of its GUI wrappers should be able to do anything you need.

Comment: How can I create charts with Graphviz? I can't find any examples...

Comment: ... that's because apparently I'm an idiot, and several people were as caffeine deprived as me when I answered the question. GraphVis is more for hierarchical/node based graphs, not bar graphs and pie charts. I've added a more sane answer below that should be vastly more useful to you. (although GraphVis is exceptionally good at what it does do)

Answer (score 0):

The [R language](http://freshmeat.net/articles/creating-charts-and-graphs-with-gnu-r) can be used to create bar and pie chart graphs. An example extracted from their help page:

```
> d <- read.table("data/EU-2004.csv", header=TRUE)     # read data
> pie(d$seats,                                         # create pie chart with seats column
+ labels=d$abbrev,                                     # use abbrev column for slice labels
+ main="2004 EU Parliament Results\n(Seats by Party)") # create pie chart
```

Later, they have an example where this sort of output is sent to a jpeg. I didn't see PNG output. It may be available, but worst case, a jpeg can easily be converted to a PNG.

Answer (score 0):

There is one great tool, which is, unfortunately, not so good at creating pie charts, but I cant help mentioning it

It is called `gnuplot`

Resources are:

http://www.gnuplot.info/

http://www.gnuplotting.org/

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/

http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.ru/

Comment: I also found this topic